# React link to static html page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux

i have a React + Redux app, i want to link to a privacy.html page which is a static html file in the root of the project along side with index.html which is the react app.

The problem is that the link to `/privacy.html` is caught by the `<Route path='*' component={NotFoundView} />`

Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 8):

Don't use `Link` for pages outside of your app. Simply use a standard `<a>` tag.

Comment: This isn't working for me; React is still intercepting the `<a>` tag link and trying to route it.